# Reference to multimap object

Tags: c++, object, reference, multimap

Is it possible to return a reference of an object inside a multimap? This is what I'm trying:

```
return &this->noteList.find(key)->second;
```

But I'm getting `Non-const lvalue reference to type 'Note' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Note *'`so I was wondering if it's even possible, and if so, how? `notelist` is the multimap and it has `Note`objects inside it.

Comment: Your expression yields a pointer, not a reference. I think you need to drop the `&`.

Comment: Do you mean "return a pointer"? It already is a reference.

Comment: How is the return type of the method defined?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Note &getRef(Note note);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this->noteList.find(key)->second` already gives you a reference to an object inside a multimap (if `this->noteList` is a multimap).

By prefixing that expression with an ampersand (`&`), you get a pointer to such an object (if that operator is not overloaded)

Comment: I didn't know it was already returning a reference without the `&`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Then just return `second` without ampersand (`&`) as others already pointed out.

If `noteList` or your method is `const`, you must change your return type to const as well, e.g.:

```
const Note &getRef(Note note) const;
```

*Off topic:* Usually, you should also change the parameter to `const Note &note`, yielding:

```
const Note &getRef(const Note &note) const;
```

or

```
Note &getRef(const Note &note);
```

Comment: Why do I need the const keyword? I just tried it and it's working fine without.

Comment: Which one? You need `const` return only, if method or noteList is const. Pass by reference (`const Note&`) parameter is useful, if your object is large. It is not really necessary, but more efficient than pass by value.